# ssh can connect but do not login as user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, authentication

when I connect my new configured server (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server) using ssh

```
aaa@bbb:~$ ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

and after I input the password, the connection is successful but I am not log in as username but can only see a $. I need to

```
$ su username
```

and input the password one more time to login as username.

```
username@ccc:~$
```

the default user (the user created when installing the server) does not have this issue, but the users I create all have this issue, that I need to login for one more step. Note that the new users belong to a same user group but not the same as the default user.

sorry for my poor English

Comment: I have found where the problem is. when I look into the /etc/passwd, I found there is no default user shell configuration. So I just edit /bin/bash and the problem is solved. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once connected, when you can only see the $, 
type the `$ whoami` command : you should see that you are connected with username

Juste try to type `$ bash` command and the prompt should appear

Comment: thanks! it works, and then I found that I did not configure the default shell for each user

Answer (score 0):

When you create a user, you have to authorize it to have ssh permission.
By default, the default user have this permission.
What you should do is something like this:

```
sudo chmod g-w /home/your_user
sudo chmod 700 /home/your_user/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

After making this edits, you should be able to access via ssh with the user you have added permision :)

Answer (score 0):

Check .bash_profile whether exist below home directory.

`ls -l $HOME/.bash_profile`

And check the permission (644, rw-r-r), and owner or group.

If not exist the .bash_profile file, you copy or create based on other user .bash_profile file.

P.S. When the user swich, use the follow command, `su username` not reading .bash_profile needed prompt format setting up.

`$ su - username`